How can I resolve this ifxpy installation error?
I'm getting this error when I try to install the ifxpy lib. How can I solve it?
× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      <string>:175: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\l'
      <string>:175: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\l'
      Detected 64-bit Python
      Downloading : https://hcl-onedb.github.io/odbc/OneDB-Win64-ODBC-Driver.zip
      Extracting Windows ODBC files : https://hcl-onedb.github.io/odbc/OneDB-Win64-ODBC-Driver.zip
      Smart Triggers are enabled.
      error in IfxPy setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I tried updating setuptools as recommended to try to resolve it but I was unable to do so.

What's your python version? And what OS are you using?

Python 3.12.2
Windows

The stable release of ifxpy currently supports Python 2.7, 3.4 - 3.7 but your Python version is 3.12.2.
To use ifxpy, you may have to downgrade to a supported version, perhaps python 3.7.
